# How to display all options of a dropdown list on the website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdownlist (SELECT1) that looks like this:

```
<select id="ff_elem263">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Choose amount</option>
<option value="32">50</option>
<option value="52">100</option>
<option value="78">150</option>
<option value="95">200</option>
<option value="119">250</option>
<option value="606">1500</option>
</select>
```

I need two outputs in columns:
**First** I need to display all options on the website using HTML output like this:

(Options only - first index line which says "Choose amount" needs to be ignored)
Expected output like this:

```
50
100
150
200
250
1500
```

---

**Secondly** I need to display the result of a calculation where the numbers are devided by **another variable** which *already has been created beforehand*.

Let us call the variable "devider" and - as an example - set it to 3.
So 50/3 =  16,6666, 100/3 = 33,3333 etc. etc.

So the second column would look like this:

```
16,6666
33,3333
50
66,6663
83,3333
500
```

I will add those numbers to a div with ID=demo2

**As an endresult I will need this:**

```
50 16,6666
100 33,3333
150 50
200 66,6663
250 83,3333
1500 500
```

I tried to mix different approaches - but without luck. I wasn't even able to just output the first column displaying the options only. (Not the values).

Example 1.
This one displays the options in a popup. But I need it as text on my website:

```
$(function(){
    var values = $('select').children('option').map(function(i,e){
       return e.innerText;
    }).get();

    alert(values);
});
```

---

Example 2: console.log.
I tried this one also, but could not figure out how to pickup the data from my SELECT1 element instead. And also avoid using console.log altogether. It would be better to directly output the text on my website.

```
var friends_arr = ["Sonarika","Vishal","Sunil","Vijay"];

$(document).ready(function(){
 $.each(friends_arr, function(index,value){
  console.log( index + " : " + value );
 });
});
```

I am currently using this one for experimenting:

```
<p id=demo1></p>

$(function(){
    var values = $('select1').children('option').map(function(i,e){
       return e.innerText;
    }).get();

    alert(values);
});
```

But how can I output the result as HTML text to my DIV ID=demo1? Also I think here needs to be added some kind of splitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it will helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ff_elem263 option").each(function()
  {
 if($(this).val() != "0"){
           var val = parseInt($(this).html())/3;
      $("#demo2").append("<label>"+$(this).html()+" "+val.toFixed(4)+"<label>");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
label{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ff_elem263">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Choose amount</option>
<option value="32">50</option>
<option value="52">100</option>
<option value="78">150</option>
<option value="95">200</option>
<option value="119">250</option>
<option value="606">1500</option>
</select>

<div id="demo2">

</div>
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot Udhay! Worked like a charm.  I am using another so I had to chance the script to this:  

`jQuery('#ff_elem263 option').each(function()
  {
    if(jQuery(this).val() != '0'){
           var val = parseInt(jQuery(this).html())/3;
       jQuery('#demo').append('<label>'+jQuery(this).html()+' '+val+'<label>');
    }
  });`
  
I am not sure about the rules on stack owerflow - but is it ok to ask how to minimize the numbers to eg. 4 digits after the point?  
33.333333333333336 = 33.3336

Comment: for fix 4 digits use `val.toFixed(4)` it will works or check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var values = [];
$('#ff_elem263 option').each(function() { 
    values.push( $(this).attr('value') );
    if($(this).attr('value') != 0){
      $( "#demo" ).append("<div>"+$( this ).text()+"::"+$( this ).text()/3+"</div><br/>");
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ff_elem263">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Choose amount</option>
<option value="32">50</option>
<option value="52">100</option>
<option value="78">150</option>
<option value="95">200</option>
<option value="119">250</option>
<option value="606">1500</option>
</select>
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi labu4db

Thank you so much for your help!

Your solution worked as well. I decided to give Udhay Titus the point since he added the answer first :)

Comment: you are welcome @Ironhand. no problem and thanks for your message. if this answer is useful then you can give votes in this answer.

Comment: ahhh, thanks for the tip. I did not know that. I voted. My reputation is too low for public view - but it is counted :)